# How to total sum along with decimal value in angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How to `total sum` along with `decimal value` , actually I got the `total sum value` but the `decimal value` is not `calculated`...[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UNIkvAp4BMiJ2nfzbLkz?p=preview)   **For Example** :- fob value totalsum I got 700, Expecting like 700.57, then convertion rate value total sum I got 124, Expecting like 124.10  , If any one knows the solution help to us thanks....

**My controller:-**

```
.filter('sumOfValue', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        debugger;
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;        
        var sum = 0;

        angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
            sum = sum + parseInt(v[key]);
        });        
        return sum;
    }
})
```

**My Html:-**

```
<td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'invoice_value_fob'}}</td>

     <td>{{resultValue | sumOfValue:'conversion_rate'}}</td>
```

**My Data:-**

```
$scope.sryarndebitnote = [
    {
    "_id": "57ac1b6d82e1c5940ac3c730",
    "user": {
    "_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
    "displayName": "mani selvam"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "2016-08-11T06:30:05.118Z",
    "shipment_id": "57ac19b982e1c5940ac3c72f",
    "conversion_rate": "62.04",
    "invoice_value_fob_currency": "Rs",
    "invoice_value_fob": "300.231",
    "invoice_quantity_unit": "KG",
    "invoice_quantity": "37",
    "invoice_date": "2016-08-17",
    "supplier_name": "Msd",
    "buyer_name": "Mani selvam .R"
    },

    {
    "_id": "57b5af69df0475401f644b2e",
    "user": {
    "_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
    "displayName": "mani selvam"
    },
    "__v": 0,
    "created": "2016-08-18T12:51:53.671Z",
    "shipment_id": "57b5af5bdf0475401f644b2d",
    "conversion_rate": "62.06",
    "exclusive": true,
    "invoice_value_fob": "400.343",
    "invoice_quantity": "97",
    "supplier_name": "Msd",
    "buyer_name": "Mani selvam .R"
    },]
```

Then I need `decimal value` in `two digit` like `700.57`,  Not like `700.574` please help us thanks....

I have created Plunker for reference:- [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UNIkvAp4BMiJ2nfzbLkz?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should solve your problem

[Here](http://gsferreira.com/archive/2015/02/angularjs-input-number-with-two-decimal-places/)

```
<input type="number" name="myDecimal" placeholder="Decimal" ng-model="myDecimal" *step="0.01"* />
```

Saw your plunker. Can you change your sumOfValue filter to following:-

```
app.filter('sumOfValue', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        debugger;
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;        
        var sum = 0;

        angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
            sum = sum + parseFloat(v[key]);
        });        
        return sum.toFixed(2);
    }
```

Adding working plunker link  [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CgzOS0mqyJxd4tnP00y4?p=preview)

Comment: thanks for your valuable comment, i have used to get a total sum like $filter functionality in my controller , so can you please look at `my plunker` for the reference , then can you update the plunker as well to understand...thanks...

Comment: the above given answer is not working in my localhost , so can you please provide the another solution...thanks.. please update the plunker, then `.toFixed(2)` it's working but total sum displaying like `700.00` only so please check and update....

Comment: thank you soo much for the updated plunker it's really very usefull to us....we got the answer... thanks a lot.....